# Static value inheritance

Tags: c++

I want each class to have its own static code, which can be requested from each object. I am thinking of this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent {
protected:
    static int code;
public:
    int getCode();
};

int Parent::code = 10;
int Parent::getCode() {
  return code;
}

class Child : public Parent {
protected:
    static int code;
};

int Child::code = 20;

int main() {
  Child c;
  Parent p;

  std::cout << c.getCode() << "\n";
  std::cout << p.getCode() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

> 10
>
> 10

yet I expect

> 20
>
> 10

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't work", may be you can show some real code and the output vs expected out?

Comment: "I want each class to have its own static code, which can be requested from each object." Theres a thing for that it's called a virtual method.

Comment: @Borgleader That should be an answer.

Comment: @Borgleader I don't see what virtual member functions have to do with that. There's no polymorphism here. By "code", he appears to mean an integer value.

Comment: I updated my question with a piece of compilable, runnable code.

Comment: is it needed to be able to change the Codes (the IDs) during runtime? Do the IDs have to be unique?

Comment: @wonkorealtime they are hardcoded and never change

Comment: Because they are hardcoded to never change, I will update my answer to a simpler version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the 'getCode()' function as virtual and have to implement every time as following codes:

```
class Parent {
protected:
    static int code;
public:
    virtual int getCode() { return code; }
};

int Parent::code = 10;

class Child : public Parent {
protected:
    static int code;
public:
    virtual int getCode() { return code; }
};

int Child::code = 20;

int main() 
{
    Child c;
    Parent p;

    std::cout << c.getCode() << "\n";
    std::cout << p.getCode() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The static variables are not needed when the values are constant (as described in OPs comments).

Comment: @abelenky, you are correct but I've tried to give a solution with less change of the original source code.

Comment: You don't need to have virtual methods if you don't access the child object with a pointer to a base class like in his example, overriding the method is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent {
public:
    virtual int getCode();

    // Looks like a variable, but actually calls the virtual getCode method.
    // declspec(property) is available on several, but not all, compilers.
    __declspec(property(get = getCode)) int code;
};


class Child : public Parent {
public:
    virtual int getCode();
};

int Parent::getCode() { return 10; }
int Child::getCode()  { return 20; }

int main() {
  Child c;
  Parent p;

  std::cout << c.code << "\n"; // Result is 20
  std::cout << p.code << "\n"; // Result is 10

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I will always have to use a member variable per class? Not to mention implement `getCode` every time.

Comment: Simpler to put the static value in the function body I think.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the member variable at all?

```
class Parent {
public:
    static int getCode();
};

int Parent::getCode() {
  return 10;
}

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    static int getCode();
};

int Child::getCode() {
  return 20;
}
```

Instead of one static member per class, you have one member function per class. Plain and simple.

Comment: A static value is not const, and could still be updated.  Your code, however, can never change the value of the codes returned.   (that may be OK for the poster... but was not described in the question)

Comment: @abelenky Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:

In the parent class, you don't declare your getCode function as virtual.
     So, whenever you call it with a class that inherits from your parent class,
     it will just return the int code from the parent class.

To fix this:

- First, declare the getCode function as virtual in your parent class.
- Second, write another getCode function in your inherited class and return
  the int code from the inherited class